# Background Image fixed issues while using jquery mobile & phonegap on mobile

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to get an app working with a fixed background image, so when it scrolls the image stays in the same position.

On desktop browsers this works fine.  When i use phonegap and run it on my android device, the background image jumps and then reappears in the correct position whenever you scroll the page.

I have looked through stack overflow and through google but have not come up with a fix for this.

I have tried adding the background image to .ui-page, body and also with adding a div around it, but whenever you go to scroll the page in the app on android the background jumps.

I have also tried changing the position to link it to top, center bottom etc, but nothing is working.

The header and footer are fixed and am using jquery mobile 1.1, with phonegap 1.2.

If anything else is needed I will share what I can

Comment: Same problem here, although not using phonegap. did you solve?

Comment: No I havent solved it.  Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap uses the androids native browser and position:fixed is only supported since android browser version 2.2.

Source: http://caniuse.com/css-fixed